# How to create a subclass with restrictions?

Tags: c#

Can we create a subclass of a base class, like creating a view of a table in SQL, in C#?

Example of desired behaviour:

```
public class EmployeeSpecificUsage : Employee
{
    public string firstName;
    public string field1;
    public int age;

    public string Name;    //Error! Not implemented in main class
}

public abstract class Employee
{
    public string firstName;
    public string lastname;
    public int age;
    public string workTitle;
    public string field1;
    public string field2;
    public string field3;
}
```

**Objectives:**

- Reduce the number of field members visible.
- Forbid adding new fields, respecting the original model.

Comment: I guess, you mean an `Interface`, not a subclass.

Comment: Views and subclasses are completely different things. A view is some prepared and stored query that is executed against a database. A subclass is simply an object whith different/extentded behaviour towards its base-class. You should consider read some basics on OOP first. What do you actually want to achieve? Hide some fields of your base-class and append some new ones?

Comment: Having `Name` class member in `EmployeeSpecificUsage` sublass is totally valid. As mentioned by @HimBromBeere I'd also suggest reading the books first... Plus recommend deleting this question.

Comment: @HimBromBeere hiding base fields and not being able to add new ones.

Comment: Your edit is confusing, as what you want to do is reduce the number of visible members on the one hand and simultaneously add totally different members (`Name`). So I guess your two classes should be completely independent without any inheritance.

Comment: @Alex I'm asking for a way not to be valid.

Comment: @Gugas If you don't want to add any fields, mark your `Employee` class as `Sealed` and do not derive from it at all.

Comment: @Alex how can I make it sealed if I want to create a sub set of the main class? I suggest you try to make sure you understand the question before "spiting" a response.

Comment: @HimBromBeere have re-edited. If they were completely different, me or my colleagues, would be able to create classes that do not respect the base "data model" which I want to force.

Comment: @Gugas Why would you want to extend the main class in the first place if you're not adding any new functionality?

Comment: @Alex Avoid confusion to future users of the classes, trying to extend methods but keep variables equal or lower to the base convention/specification.

Comment: @Gugas Ok, interface is the the correct answer then... Inheritance does not support it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An interface gives you access to an aspect of a class (as opposed to a derived class that actually extends the base class).

Have a look at this:

```
public class Employee : IEmployeeSpecificUsage
{
    public string firstName { get; }
    public string lastname { get; }
    public int age { get; }
    public string workTitle { get; }
    public string field1 { get; }
    public string field2 { get; }
    public string field3 { get; }
}

public interface IEmployeeSpecificUsage
{
    public string firstName { get; }
    public string field1 { get; }
    public int age { get; }
}
```

If you reference to an `Employee` instance by the `IEmployeeSpecificUsage` interface, you will only "see" what's in the interface.

You cannot add new interfaces without changing the "base class", though, as it has to declare that it implements those interfaces.

Comment: IEmployeeSpecificUsage e = new Employee() Very easy actually, sorry all. I was almost there. Also I wanted to be able to override / extend methods, but I will just be resorting to extensions methods for now. Do you have a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of subclassing is incorrect. Subclassing is a way of *extending* the base class, not *taking away* from it. Whatever a base class has, all subclasses would have it as well.

This is different from views in SQL, which can both take away columns and also add computed columns.

Although *inheritance* does not allow you to reduce the number of visible members, you can do it with *composition*. Wrap `Employee` in a `RestrictedEmployee`, and expose only the members that you want others to see:

```
public class EmployeeSpecificUsage {
    private readonly Employee wrapped;
    public EmployeeSpecificUsage(Employee e) {
        wrapped = e;
    }
    public string firstName => wrapped.firstName;
    public string field1 => wrapped.field1;
    // Two fields above use C# 6 syntax. If it is not available,
    // use syntax below:
    public int age {
        get {
            return wrapped.age;
        }
    }
}
```

As far as prohibiting the addition of new fields goes, you cannot do that with either inheritance or composition: if you are allowed to subclass at all (i.e. the base class is not `sealed`) you would be able to add new members. Composition is a lot weaker than inheritance, so you could add new fields even to `sealed` classes by wrapping them.

Comment: Subclass implies Inheritance not extension. Also in the title was "derived", someone edited it, It could also be called a sub set class...

Comment: Anyway you answered my question although the answer from @Haukinger looks cleaner.

Comment: @Gugas the differences between the two answers is that the other one requires an ability to modify the class, and is easily circumvented by a cast.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces can be used as views.

```
public interface IView
{
    string FirstName { get; }
    int Age { get; }
    string Name { get; }
}

public class Employee: IView
{
     // make fields private if possible         
     private string firstName;
     private string lastname;
     private int age;
     private string workTitle;
     private string field1;
     private string field2;
     private string field3;

     // implements IView.FirstName as an auto property
     public string FirstName { get; set; }

     // implements IView.Age: returns the private age field
     public int Age { get { return age;} } 

     // explicit implementation of IView.Name: visible only as IView
     string IView.Name { get { return lastName + ", " + firstName; } }
}
```

And then:

```
Employee employee1 = new Employee(); // FirstName and Age are visible on employee1
IView employee2 = new Employee(); // Name is visible, too
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide a readonly access to an inner field of a class check out public **Properties with getter**. Make you field members protected. In such a way you will have an ability to implement custom logic for **Name** property composing it from firstname and lastname field.

```
public class EmployeeSpecificUsage : Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get { return firstName; }};
    public string FullName { get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", firstName, lastName); }};
}

public class Employee
{
    protected string firstName;
    protected string lastname;
    protected int age;
    protected string workTitle;
    protected string field1;
    protected string field2;
    protected string field3;
}
```

An option would be to create properties in the base class with protected setters and public getters.